# Is inheritance allowed for EJB3 Stateless Session Beans?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1, openejb

Suppose I have a stateless bean:

```
@Stateless(name = "fooBean")
@LocalBean
public class Foo {
...
}
```

I want to create a mock for testing (with CDI)

```
@Alternative @Specializes
public class FooMock extends Foo {
...
}
```

I register the mock in `beans.xml`, and when I run it with OpenEJB, I get the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException:
openejb/Deployment/fooBean/com.company.Foo!LocalBeanHome
```

It seems to me that the container creates an interface for `Foo` because of `@LocalBean` which is now implemented by `FooMock`, too. OpenEJB tries to bind the two classes with the with same name of same generated interface, which is not possible.

Of course, if I comment out `@Stateless` and `@LocalBean` in `Foo` class, it works fine.

Any idea or suggestion to solve this?

Comment: It should be possible to subclass the EJB class; the subclass won't be an EJB, but if you're just testing then it won't matter.  What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather do something like:

```
@Local
public interface Foo {
...
}

@Stateless
public class FooBean implements Foo {
...
}
```

Then make your mock.

```
@Alternative
@Specializes
public class FooMock implements Foo {
...
}
```

However I recommend you take a look at [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) it will make your testing so much easier without the need for @Alternative and special beans.xml entries for tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with a separate interface, that is working, but also that is what we wanted avoid :) . Arquillian seems to be a great framework, I will check it out...

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to avoid the interface? @LocalBean is great and useful in many cases, however if you will be using mocks it  is probably a good idea to use an interface.